# Java parse date using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a English date from String format to Date and if possible get it as **French format**.

For example I get something in this format : `"2014-07-21T14:31:08+0200"`
I am using this line but this raise a ParseException any idea ?

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Z");
```

Comment: there is a `.` in front of the `Z` but not in your example date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `.` in front of the `Z` inside the format.

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2014-07-21T14:31:08+0200");
```

happily parses.